# Silverlight Testing EnqueueCallback in loops

Tags: silverlight, unit-testing

I am writing Silverlight tests that rely on data loaded at the start of the test, something like this:

```
string[] testVectors = new string[20];
EnqueueCallback( Load some data );
EnqueueConditional( Wait for loading of data to finish );
EnqueueCallback( Populate testVectors using the loaded data );
```

Next I want to enqueue more callbacks and conditions using the test vectors.  But how do I loop?????

I can't do this:

```
for(int iTest=0; iTest<20; iTest++ )
{
   EnqueueConditional( Run test for testVector[iTest] );
   EnqueueConditional( Wait for test to finish );
}
```

...because the test vector strings do not exists when the for loop runs.

Any ideas?

Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you want to do is queue another action to execute later, it just happens that this action includes queueing some more dependent actions.

What you can do is enqueue a callback which nests the remainder of your test, either directly or by chaining to another method.

```
EnqueueCallback(...);
...
EnqueueCallback(() => 
{
    for(int iTest=0; iTest<20; iTest++ )
    {
        EnqueueConditional( ... );
    }
});
```

Just probably don't want to then put anything un-nested below the nested callback - it can be executed/queued before the nested things.

Comment: Thanks!  Didn't think I could call an Enqueue from inside an Enquqe.